# Find Max Average of Dictionary Values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have another fill in the blank that I'm not sure how to answer.
I have a problem where i need to *fill in the blanks* in this code; where the blanks are sections like `[x1]`, `[x2]`, etc.

```
grades = {"Sam": [85, 90, 95], "Sue": [82, 96, 91], "Ted": [30, 59, 43], "Pat": [72, 75, 78]}

highest = 0

for [x1]:

    exams = grades[student]

    average = 0

    for [x2]:

        average += exam

    average = average / [x3]

    # Make sure that "highest" holds the highest average score.

    if [x4]:

        [x5]

print(highest)
```

The solutions i've tried so far are:

`[x1]` = `grades in student`

`[x2]` = `grade in range(len(student))`

`[x3]` = `sum(exams)`

I'm not sure if these are correct, and i have no idea what to try for `[x4]` and `[x5]`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Echo Martijn Pieters: Show us something that you've tried, please.

Comment: I have placed in some of the code I had filled in, but I was definitely clueless on the last two. I meant to do that and forgot.

Comment: @Ashley Following Mr Pieters and Mr Long(?) I will simply remark how poor is the title you choose for your question

Comment: Well whatever this is, it's certainly not valid Python. Are those `[x1]:` bits the "blanks"? I have no idea what you're trying to ask here. Have you tried running your code and seeing what (errors) it produces? That's usually a good place to start, when wondering whether some code works.

Comment: Yes, the only error I am running right now is 'highest = 0' is giving it fits. I'm about to take it out and rename it somewhere else or rename it entire to see if it'll run the rest of my code.

Comment: The [x1]: are where the blanks are being placed. I left them in to show where exactly the fill in the blanks are and what can be changed.

Comment: I've edited the question to ask what i believe was meant.

Answer (score 0):

So i believe you've been tasked with printing out the student with the highest average mark;

```
grades = {"Sam": [85, 90, 95], "Sue": [82, 96, 91], "Ted": [30, 59, 43], "Pat": [72, 75, 78]}

highest = 0

for [x1]:

    exams = grades[student]

    average = 0

    for [x2]:

        average += exam

    average = average / [x3]

    # Make sure that "highest" holds the highest average score.

    if [x4]:

        [x5]

print(highest)
```

`highest` clearly has to hold the highest mark, as it starts as zero, and i presume you're only allowed to change the *blanks*;

`grades` holds all the information, so it is clearly what you need to iterate through, where you'll need to know how `dict` objects behave when you iterate through them.

if you have something like:

```
myDictionary = {keyObject1: valueObject1, keyObject2: valueObject2, keyObject3: valueObject3}
```

there are several ways of iterating through this dictionary, either provided by the default behaviour, or through class methods of `dict`;

`for thing in myDictionary:...` will iterator over each entry in the dictionary, and set `thing` to be the current `key` of the dictionary.

`for thing in myDictionary.keys():...` will do the same as above, but is a little more explicit. It does the same as `myDictionary.keys()` returns a list of all the `key`s of the dictionary, which is then iterated over like a normal list.

`for thing in myDictionary.values()` will, you guessed it, do the same as above, except `thing` will be the current `value` of the dictionary.

the other option is the best in most cases, as it makes for more readable and concise code; `for thing in myDictionary.items():...` iterates through the dictionary setting `thing` to a `tuple`, `(key, value)`, for each dictionary entry. I have used `thing` in each of these examples, but normally you will see what is below:

```
for key in myDictionary:
  pass

for key in myDictionary.keys():
  pass

for value in myDictionary.values():
  pass

for key, value in myDictionary.items():
  pass
```

Where the last one unpacks the tuple into the two values. Often, `key` / `value` is replaced by some other variable name which makes more sense.

So for your first `blank`, you're iterating through the `grades` dictionary, where the `keys` are student names, so you have a couple of choices for `[x1]`;

```
for student in grades:....
```

or

```
for student in grades.keys():....
```

this will make `student` hold the name of the student for each loop, and then the next line; `exams = grades[student]` will contain that student's exam results.

The next section is just a calculation of the average mark for each student, sum up all of the results, and divide by the number of results.

again, it is simply looping through the array of exam results.

look at the folowing code;

```
myNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for myNumber in myNumbers:
  print myNumber
```

This will print `1 2 3 4 5 6` (on a new line each time). this is because the `for ... in ...:` construct iterates through whatever you give it setting the variable equal to the current element. You need to iterate through the exam results stored in the `exams` array, and then divide by the total number of exam results.

currently, you are iterative through `range(len(student))`. `len(myArray)` does exactly what you think it does, it just gives you the length of `myArray`, so in this case it's going to be `2` for every student. `range(myNumber)` gives an array, `[0, 1, ... myNumber]`, so in your code, you're going to be calculating the average as (0+1+2) / sum(all exam results), which will always be zero here.

You need to sum up the exam results, and then divide them by the number of exam results.

As for the last two variables, this part is trying to work out if the current average is the highest average, so it should test if the current average is greater than `highest`, and then if it is, update `highest`.

Hopefully this should be all you need to complete the rest of the `blanks`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_highest_average(grades):
    return max(sum(scores)/len(scores) for scores in grades.values())
```

This function will return the highest average in the dictionary `grades`. It uses a generator comprehension to calculate the average of each list of scores and then passes them to the `max()` built in to find the highest value, which is returned.